# Data validation in Laravel is not working

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-6

I've created a custom request in my project, but somehow it is not working. I'm facing two errors. I'm trying to show a message on view if validation fails through Ajax.

> 1) 422 Unprocessable Entity error

and

> 2) Undefined variable: teacherrequest

validation  rules which i set in Request folder,

**TeacherRequest.php:**

```php
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'Name' => 'required|regex:/^[\pL\s\-]+$/u',
        'FName' => 'required|regex:/^[\pL\s\-]+$/u',
    ];
}
```

**Controller:**

```php
public function update(TeacherRequest $request, $id)
{
    if ($teacherrequest->fails()) {
        return response()->json([
            'msg' => 'Please Enter Correct Data',
        ]);
    }
}
```

**AJAX:**

```
success: function (data) {

if(data.msg){
        alert("please validate data");

}
}
```

**Update:**

if i remove if condition, i am getting 422 error, how to show that on view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `public function update(TeacherRequest $request)` so in the function you need to use `$request` not `$teacherrequest`.

And second You need to have `public function authorize()` returning true.

Comment: that's true, how can i show message on view, from json,if there is validation error?

Comment: What's the output of `console.log(data)` ?

Comment: According to Laravel Docs: 
    however, if validation fails, an exception will be thrown and the proper error  response will automatically be sent back to the user. In the case of a traditional HTTP request, a redirect response will be generated, while a JSON response will be sent for AJAX requests.

Comment: console.logo(data) returns data is not defined.  error: function(xhr){
                  console.log(data);
                },

Comment: You don't need to do the check if you are using A Validation Class.
If the validation fails, it will send a JSON response.
So if you console.log your data you will have an error property

Answer (score 0):

You define TeacherRequest as $request `TeacherRequest $request`

but in next line use it as

```
if ($teacherrequest->fails()){ // this is wrong
```

correct one should be define like this

```
TeacherRequest $teacherrequest
```

or if you didn't change the dependency injection, just change the validator like this

```
if ($request->fails()){
```

summary: why error happened already specifically explained which is undefined `teacherrequest` variable, therefore 2 solutions above can solve it

Comment: Method App\Http\Requests\TeacherRequest::fails does not exist.

Comment: if i remove if condition, i am getting 422 error, how to show that on view?

Comment: actually if you use dependency injection like that, you don't need to check it via condition again

Comment: can i send custom message in json if there's validation error?

Answer (score 0):

If you type hint your request class as a parameter in your controller's action method (like you are doing in the example above) Laravel will automatically run your validation rules and return a `422 Unprocessable Entity` if validation fails. You don't need to manually check if validation fails like you're doing above; in your controller's `update` method you can just implement the logic you want to run when validation passes.

Also on your front end you will need to use the `error` ajax callback to display the error message because a `422` status code is not considered successful.

See the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#creating-form-requests) on creating form requests.

> So, how are the validation rules evaluated? All you need to do is type-hint the request on your controller method. The incoming form request is validated before the controller method is called, meaning you do not need to clutter your controller with any validation logic.

Comment: with: public function update(TeacherRequest $teacherrequest, $id) 
Error: Method App\Http\Requests\TeacherRequest::fails does not exist

Comment: if i remove if condition, i am getting 422 error, how to show that on view?

Comment: The `422` is an expected error in this case. That's the validation failing. To show it in your view, you will need to use the `error` ajax callback to display the error message (instead of the `success` callback like in your example). Check out the error callback setting: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings

Comment: can i send custom message in json if there's validation error?

Comment: Yes. Check out the documentation for Laravel validation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#customizing-the-error-messages